# R underperforming on dplyr summarize with multiple joins and filters

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have the following example dataset containing 3 dataframes:

```
base_pop_ex <-
  structure(
    list(
      anon_id = c(
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7"
      ),
      session_number = c(1,
                         2),
      entrance_date = c("2021-06-28 11:43:21.633 Z", "2021-06-29 01:10:08.109 Z"),
      single_article_session = c(0, 0)
    ),
    .Names = c(
      "anon_id",
      "session_number",
      "entrance_date",
      "single_article_session"
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

ad_views_ex <-
  structure(
    list(
      anon_id = c(
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7"
      ),
      ad_view_date = c(
        "2021-06-28 11:43:22.654 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:44:15.360 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:44:32.538 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.557 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:20.146 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:10:08.706 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:10:17.127 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:40:30.726 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:40:30.914 Z"
      ),
      ad_call_count = c(3, 1, 1, 1, 3,
                        3, 1, 1, 3)
    ),
    .Names = c("anon_id", "ad_view_date", "ad_call_count"),
    row.names = c(NA,-9L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

scroll_depth_ex <-
  structure(
    list(
      anon_id = c(
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7",
        "0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7"
      ),
      scroll_date = c(
        "2021-06-28 11:43:38.263 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:43:41.593 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:43:48.882 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:43:49.339 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:43:52.270 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:43:57.995 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:44:15.324 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:44:16.955 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:44:30.284 Z",
        "2021-06-28 11:44:44.197 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.564 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.581 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.593 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.600 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.617 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.639 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.648 Z",
        "2021-06-28 12:07:19.664 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:10:13.401 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:10:25.065 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:11:02.595 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:11:45.444 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:40:30.741 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:40:30.747 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:40:30.903 Z",
        "2021-06-29 01:40:30.909 Z"
      ),
      scroll_depth = c(
        10,
        20,
        30,
        40,
        50,
        60,
        70,
        80,
        90,
        100,
        10,
        20,
        30,
        40,
        50,
        60,
        70,
        80,
        10,
        20,
        30,
        40,
        10,
        20,
        30,
        40
      )
    ),
    .Names = c("anon_id", "scroll_date",
               "scroll_depth"),
    row.names = c(NA,-26L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

I want to join all three data frames, so at the end, I get `anon_id`, `entrance_date`, `session_number`, `ad_views` and `scroll_depth`:

- `ad_views` is the sum of all ad_call_counts of the data frame `ad_views_ex` where the `ad_view_date` is greater than the `entrance_date` from the table `base_pop_ex` and, at the same time, the difference in minutes between both dates is smaller than 60
- `scroll_depth` uses the same logic, for the join, as the previous metric. However, I am calculating the max for each group of events here

The following code does its job:

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

combined_ex <- base_pop_ex %>%
      left_join(ad_views_ex, by = c("anon_id")) %>%
      filter(
        entrance_date <= ad_view_date &
          difftime(ad_view_date, entrance_date, units = "mins") <= 60
      ) %>%
      group_by(anon_id, entrance_date, session_number) %>%
      summarize(
        ad_views = sum(ad_call_count, na.rm = TRUE)
        )
      )
    
    combined_ex2 <- combined_ex %>%
      left_join(scroll_depth_ex, by = c("anon_id")) %>%
      filter(
        entrance_date <= scroll_date &
          difftime(scroll_date, entrance_date, units = "mins") <= 60
      ) %>%
      group_by(anon_id, entrance_date, session_number, ad_views) %>%
      summarize(
        scroll_depth = max(scroll_depth, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
    )
```

with the final outcome of `combined_ex2` this:

```
|               anon_id              |       entrance_date        | session_number | ad_views | scroll_depth |
|------------------------------------|----------------------------|----------------|----------|--------------|
|0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7| 2021-06-28 11:43:21.633 Z  |       1        |   162    |      100     |      
|0003ff12-03b1-42b9-86cf-4b7c05e3e3a7| 2021-06-29 01:10:08.109 Z  |       2        |    64    |      40      |
```

However, when I scale that to my real data, Rstudio takes about 1 minute to create the first combined data frame, and 8 minutes to create the second combined data frame. My data contains 500K rows for `base_pop_ex`, 1.4M rows for `ad_views_ex` and 3.7M rows for `scroll_depth_ex`, what I do not consider too much.

- Can anyone tell me why my code is underperforming on my data?
- Also, is there a way to do the same job without having to split the join, group, and summarizes in two steps?

Comment: Your datetimes are stored as character. Does converting to datetimes help at all? Otherwise, I think the main bottleneck is that you're doing a non-equi join with the timestamps, which dplyr doesn't handle natively. The workaround of a join+filter will tend to grow in memory and time with the square of your data, so it will likely be much faster to use a data.table or sqldf solution which handles non-equi joins.

Comment: One simple way to speed this up would be to add `dtplyr::lazy_dt() %>%` in your 2nd line and `as_tibble()` at the end. That shifts the calculations to `data.table`, which is faster than dplyr for calculating on grouped data. In my testing that speeds it up about 2x. But to go much faster I think a non-equi join in data.table or sqldf will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I shifted the calculations to `data.table` and it went much faster... However, what I ended doing was generating the combined dataframe directly using `sqldf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the `filter()` step. Experiment with separating the two parts, putting the `difftime()` second.

ex:

```
  ...
  filter(entrance_date <= ad_view_date) %>%
  filter(difftime(ad_view_date, entrance_date, units = "mins") <= 60) %>%
  ...
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it is taking about the same time to complete. Results are ok tho.